# JQuery will not run to submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am probably missing something simple.  The JQuery on this page does not run.  That is obvious because the alert does not execute.  I am simply trting to submit the form without the page refreshing.  Also, I am not getting console errors. Thanks in advance.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
       $('submitpicks').on('submit','#submitpicks',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();  //this will prevent reloading page
            alert('Form submitted Without Reloading');
       });
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="submitpicks" id="submitpicks" action="" method="post">
<script type="">
var v=0;
function acceptpick(thepick,removepick){
    var userPick = confirm("You picked " + thepick + ". Accept this pick?");
    //var theid = "finalpick" + v;
    var removebtn = "btn" + removepick;
    //alert(theid);
    if(userPick==1){
        document.getElementById("finalpick").value=removepick;
        document.getElementById(removebtn).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("submitpicks").submit();
        v=v+1;
    }
}
</script>
<?php
include "Connections/myconn.php";
//$setid = $_SESSION["gbsid"];
$setid = 11;
$setqry = "Select * from grabBagParticipants where gbsid = $setid order by rand()";
$setresult = mysqli_query($conn, $setqry);
$u=0;
if(mysqli_num_rows($setresult)>0){
    while($setrow = mysqli_fetch_array($setresult)){
        //shuffle($setrow);
        echo '<input type="button" name="' . $setrow["gbpid"] . '" id="btn' . $setrow["gbpid"] . '" value="' . $u . '" onClick=\'acceptpick("' . $setrow["gbpname"] . '", ' . $setrow["gbpid"] . ');\' /><br />';
        $u=$u+1;
    }
}
?>
<input type="text" name="finalpick" id="finalpick" />
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
<div id="results">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$('submitpicks')` ==> `$('#submitpicks')`. And use `$('submitpicks').on('submit', function() {` to bind submit event on form

Comment: If you're using jQuery, *use* jQuery. Don't do `document.getElementById("finalpick").value=removepick;`, do `$('#finalpick').val(removepick)`

Comment: @Tushar still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
   <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
       $('#submitpicks').on('submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();  //this will prevent reloading page
            alert('Form submitted Without Reloading');
       });
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="submitpicks" id="submitpicks" action="test.php" method="post">
<script type="">
var v=0;
function acceptpick(thepick,removepick){
    var userPick = confirm("You picked " + thepick + ". Accept this pick?");
    //var theid = "finalpick" + v;
    var removebtn = "btn" + removepick;
    //alert(theid);
    if(userPick==1){
        document.getElementById("finalpick").value=removepick;
        document.getElementById(removebtn).disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("submitpicks").submit();
        v=v+1;
    }
}
</script>
<input type="text" name="finalpick" id="finalpick" />
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
<div id="results">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try comment your php code and also put <script> tag out of form. Can't check your php code having databse related code else its working fine.

Comment: Updated code what is working for me, just removed php code and I am getting alert.

Comment: I see, so how do I use PHP with it? The PHP is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem. Fyi, just doing JS here which is not working for you considering no errors are showing up.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
      $('#submitpicks').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Form Submitted without reloading.');
      })
    });

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="submitpicks" id="submitpicks" action="" method="post">

  <input type="text" name="finalpick" id="finalpick" />
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
</body>
```